# Process SQS queue items and then combine the items to store the log in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have items in my SQS queue. I then grab 100 items from queue to process and then I want to store the processed items in S3.

However, the problem is that since I will be storing 100 items each, there will be numerous pieces of logs in the S3.

One way to solve this is to store 100 items locally into a file and then keep updating locally until it reaches a certain threshold. Only after that upload to S3.

Is this how it is supposed to work?

Thanks.

Comment: What logs are you talking about?

Comment: @error2007s, i'm planning to store SQS items as logs in S3 after processing from SQS. Thanks.

Comment: And how is this "One way to solve this is to store 100 items locally into a file and then keep updating" going to solve the problem I did not get it

Comment: Are you able to provide more information about what you wish to accomplish? That way, we would be better able to offer suitable advice. For example, what do you do to "process" the items -- do you merely store them in S3, or are they manipulated in some way and you simply wish to store a log of what items were processed? Does anything happen outside of the data files (eg calling external services)? Is your desire to store fewer, larger log files in S3? What problem are you trying to avoid with more, smaller log files? How will you cope with potential failures (eg before storing the log file)?

Comment: which sdk are you using to grab 100 items?